# How do I install MahApps Ui Library into an IronPython project

Tags: ironpython, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to install MahApps.metro from https://mahapps.com on a IronPython WPF project. Since I cant use nugget to install it because visual studio just don't give me this option, how can I import and use this library?

I tried install through nugget console and also get an error
 Install-Package MahApps.Metro -Version 1.6.5

Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MahApps.Metro -Version 1.6.5
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Python

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("MahApps.Metro.dll")
import MahApps.Metro
from MahApps.Metro import Controls

class MyWindow(Controls.MetroWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'DemoApp.xaml')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

XAML

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
       xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="DemoApp" Height="300" Width="300">

       <Grid></Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

It builds and seems to load the library correctly, but crashes on start,

'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rodrigo.Queiroz\source\PoCs\IPython_WPFInterface\WpfIronPy\DemoApp\MahApps.Metro.dll'. Symbols loaded.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Comment: It could be that you need to add also a reference to ControlzEx.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll which are dependencies of MahApps.Metro.

Comment: Hi @punker76, thank you for your advise, I managed to import all the necessary dependencies as you said and  the project is on going now. I can share the code here with a few tips that I got on your blog [link](https://jkarger.de/2017/02/06/mahapps-hamburgermenu/) if you don't mind of course

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out how to import the style project into my application

Steps:
1 - Nugget packages:
In order to download MahApps.Metro from Nugget a new C# Library project was created in the solution and the packages folder now is the path to these libs

2 - MahApps.Metro installation: 
After the download you have to import them into your python code with clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath as shown in the python file below

3 - Set correct type in your Python class:
Set MetroWindow type, instead Window on your class inheritance

4 - Set xmlns on your XAML files:
Set xmlns in XAML as shown in the XAML code below, like:
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

5 - Change control type in XAML:
Change control type in xaml from Window to Controls:MetroWindow

This setup was enough to get things working

Python Code:

```
import wpf
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo.Queiroz\\source\\PoCs\\WPFIronPython\\packages\\ControlzEx.3.0.2.4\\lib\\net45\\ControlzEx.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo.Queiroz\\source\\PoCs\\WPFIronPython\\packages\\ControlzEx.3.0.2.4\\lib\\net45\\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\\Users\\Rodrigo.Queiroz\\source\\PoCs\\WPFIronPython\\packages\\MahApps.Metro.1.6.5\\lib\\net45\\MahApps.Metro.dll')
from MahApps.Metro.Controls import MetroWindow
from System.Windows import Application, Window



class PageLoader(MetroWindow):
    def __init__(self , page):
       ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, page)


    def HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemClick(self,sender,e):
       self.HamburgerMenuControl.Content = e.ClickedItem
       #self.HamburgerMenuControl.IsPaneOpen = False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(PageLoader('C:\Users\Rodrigo.Queiroz\source\PoCs\WPFIronPython\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1.xaml'))
```

XAML Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
       xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
       xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Themes/HamburgerMenuTemplate.xaml" />
                <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
                <Grid Height="48">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                    FontSize="16"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="{Binding Glyph}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="{Binding Label}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
                        Foreground="White"
                        PaneBackground="#FF444444"
                        IsPaneOpen="False"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                        OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                        ItemClick="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemClick"
                        OptionsItemClick="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemClick"
                        DisplayMode="CompactInline">


    <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuItem}">
            <Grid x:Name="TheContentGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="48" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0"
                    Background="#FF444444">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Header"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="24"
                            Foreground="White"
                            Text="{Binding Label}" />
                </Border>
                <ContentControl x:Name="TheContent"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Focusable="False"
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                            Content="{Binding Tag}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>


        <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Home">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                        <Label Content="This is a Label control1." />
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Private">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                        <Label Content="This is a Label control2." />
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Settings">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                        <Label Content="This is a Label control3." />
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>

        <!--  Options  -->
        <Controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="About">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>

                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>


</Controls:MetroWindow>
```